# Google font changes in Chrome after a period of time

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-font-api

I'm currently working on a project and we've noticed on a number of machines that when leaving the page open for a few minutes, Chrome (on OSX, haven't tried on other OS flavours) will eventually drop the google fonts we've chosen;

[image: Original]

and revert to what appears to be Times.

[image: Incorrect]

This has been much more prevalent in the last day or two since the release of Chrome v32, and has happened on other sites with no relation to the site we're building.

Hovering over any instances of affected text will make Chrome update the font to its correct typeface again, and it will typically correct all instances at that time.

I'm wondering if anyone else has come across this problem before, and if there is a known work around to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a confirmed bug [(#236298)](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=236298) with Google Chrome, rather than it being an issue with your code.

Comment: So it appears there is nothing programatic that can be done to avoid this issue apart from reducing the complexity of the sites CSS, which isn't going to happen, or ride it out until v33.